# Blender Render: PNG image on semi-transparent colored object

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I need to put a png image on a semi-transparent cylinder. Like a logo on a colored cup. I need to achieve it only blender render (no cycles, because export in a 3rd party program).

SUM UP :
colored semi-transparent cylinder (like alpha 0.8, color red)
PNG logo with transparent background.
Logo is all around the cylinder, so we have to see the backface.
Logo is opaque
Logo could have several color

[image: cup reference image]

Comment: This site is for asking/answering specific questions, not step by step guides. Is there a specific issue you are having?

Comment: yes, how to make the make the transparent part of the png colored?

Comment: i made the cup semi- transparent, the logo with png, but can't mix the two. The logo is not visible behind the cup

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand what you mean, but I feel you maybe just need to enable this flag in the "shadow" section of the blender internal material settings: "receive transparent".

Here I created a (guess somewhat) similar setup, and without that flag the result is like this

[image]

while after enabling it, you can see the "hidden" image behind the semitransparent "glass"

[image]

note I here used "raytrace" transparency, but it should work with "Z transparency" too...

Answer (score 0):

In the material settings turn on *Transparency*, set the *Alpha* to something around 0.1 (this is where you set how transparent the cup will be).
[image: Transparency in material settings]

Now add an image (with alpha) in a texture slot. The most important thing is that you turn on *Alpha* in the Influence section. If you have an image with an 100% opaque part, do not set the influence all the way to 1, leave it around 0.5.  (In my example with the material's alpha at .1, and the texture's influence at .5 the final alpha of the image will be .2)

[image: texture settings]

I used a white image ([this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlcG7.png)) so I turned on *RGB to Intensity* then selected the color there.